# How to execute Add-LocalGroupMember script package from user context

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, sccm

I am trying to implement a script deployment package in SCCM which is meant to execute on freshly deployed workstation in a particular ad OU group. Problem lies within the execution rights; if i deploy package with user rights run mode `-i` get access denied, if i run it with admin right i get the wrong account added.

I've tried running the script without encoding service account credentials, however this identified the system execution account, then i added credentials and this worked only for admin users.

```
$User = $env:USERNAME 
$Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME 
$svcAcc = "xxx\svc_LocalAdmin" 
$PasswordFile = ".\Password.txt" $KeyFile = ".\AES.key" 
$key = Get-Content $KeyFile

$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $svcAcc,(Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrator" -Member $args[0]} -ArgumentList $User
```

I was expecting this to run with all accounts, as service account credentials are provided in the script. How do i achieve same results from user account context?

Many Thanks

Comment: use an _explicit, specific_ user name instead of "the current user" to determine the user to add to the local admin group.

Comment: The issue is that the solution requires the current user to be dynamic, as this script gets deployed to all workstations within a OU, only the first person to log onto a machine is meant to gain localadmin

Comment: then use something like a GPO to do that. otherwise you need to give the unknown user domain admin privs ... and that seems unwise. [*grin*]

Comment: I kmow, and i have advised the client against it - offering solutions like LAPS with no luck. GPO wont work as i cant configure it to run strictly on freshly deployed workstations and only for the first user which logs in as far as i know. My current posted solution works fine, but only as long as its executed from an admin account to begin with, which confuses me

Comment: if it's an admin account, then the `$Env:UserName` will be that account. [*grin*] ///// have you thot about using a run-once task? have it run with an admin or system account that has the needed privs & store the username somewhere that the task can find.

Comment: Yeah, but how can i target it to just freshly deployed/redeployed workstations? Right now i have a step in deployment task sequence which adds a computer to a device group, this isolates only new OS deployments and deploys a package with said sript to only run when user is logged in and to do so once.

Comment: A note here is that this solution should not apply to any currently deployed workstations, strictly redeployed or freshly deployed ones. I have also considered gui++, however there is already a solution for deployment management called Jumpstart controling that, and we have no documentation regarding its configuration.

Comment: Another idea might be to query to the TopConsole user for each machine from the SCCM database and set that user as the local admin. This only works if this is the same user as the one that logs in first to the machine of course, given your specific requirements.

Comment: your requirement is to **_[a]_** gather the 1st login user name **_[b]_** add that to the local admin group. ///// that seems to require passing `A` to `B` & i cannot think of any other way to get that done short of a run-once task. [*blush*]

Comment: I havent gotten anything running othar than that myself outside of lab environment as well, the problem is that this solution cannot be targetted to currently deployed computers and i see no way to apply GPO to freshly deployed clients only

Comment: How about, consider using psexec in your package delivery and use that to turn in the context of the user needed to complete the task.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, how could i dynamically provide the required details to psexec in an automated manner?

Comment: maybe this is just half of the code or something or I'm misinterpreting but the $cred you create before the invoke-command is not actually used anywhere so wouldn't that be the reason it doesn't work even though it has service account credentials?

Comment: You were indeed right, however - even with the credentials used i ended up with "Access denied errors when running directly on client or deploying as package. As the method in the other comment works without utilizing service account credentials - ill go with that. I don't foresee problems at the moment, as owner of explorer.exe will surely be a user account which logged in, client has not specified that this account would be remote or local so i am playing it safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you attempting to run this task against every user that potentially logs into these machines? Or is it just the currently logged in user?

For these kinds of tasks I highly recommend the [PowerShell AppDeploy Toolkit](https://psappdeploytoolkit.com/).

Using the Toolkit, you can create a script which can target the currently logged on user, which can then be deployed via SCCM. Using `Get-LoggedOnUser` gives you session details for all local and RDP logged on users without too much fuss.

Comment: Thank you - good idea that i will keep in mind for future. It is only meant to be ran against first user that logs into a freshly re/deployed computer. I ended up being able to get my idea working by running it as admin from package program settings and changing $user to following -  $User = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name='explorer.exe'" |
  ForEach-Object { $_.GetOwner() } |
  Select-Object -Unique -Expand User